# How to remove a node of a YAML document with yaml-cpp

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

I have a YAML file like:

```
top:
  names:
    - name: john1
    - name: john2
    - name: john3
    - name: john.doe
```

Now I have to remove top/names/name(john.doe). How can I achieve that with yaml-cpp? My code is:

```
void deleteNode(string id)
{
    YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("doc.yaml");
    for (int i = 0; i < config["top"]["names"].size(); i++)
    {
        if(config["top"]["names"][i]["name"].as<string>() == id)
        {
            config["top"]["names"].remove(config["top"]["names"][i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
deleteNode("john.doe");
```

This doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're dealing with a sequence, you have to remove a node by its index:

```
void deleteNode(string id) {
    YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile("doc.yaml");
    YAML::Node names = config["top"]["names"];
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        if(names[i]["name"].as<string>() == id) {
            names.remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing a node from a sequence is fixed in libyaml-cpp version **0.6.3**. You should update to that version or above if your version is older than that.